# How to read from file line by line and print in Python?

Tags: python, file

```
inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r') # Makes File object
outputFile = open("results.csv", "w")
dictionary = {} # Our "hash table"
compare = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" # urls will compare against this string

for line in inputFile:
    lineToRead = inputFile.readline()
    # ---- testing ----
    print line # for some reason this prints the last line in pets.txt which is mouse
    print str(lineToRead) # for some reason this doesn't print the current line that was read
    print lineToRead
inputFile.close()
```

For some reason the only thing that gets printed is `mouse`. My input file looks like this:

```
cat
dog
bird
mouse
```

I have never programed in Python.

Comment: Do you realize that you're skipping lines by reading through the file as you read through the file? It should just be `for line in inputFile: print line`.

Comment: Wow I never thought of that before!

Comment: @fatalError I've typed all your code by hand according to your screenshot. If you are not sure about code formatting, you can just paste your code and **indent them by four spaces** -- you code will be nicely formatted and highlighted. Anyway, please do use text instead of images for code so that others can edit the question to improve formatting.

Comment: Sorry for the sarcasm. I read documentation and I have experience in OOD so I thought I could just get by looking at the documentation as I went along.

Comment: That exactly what I tried but I was getting an error about explaining my code and making sure my formatting was correct? After 15 minutes I just took a screenshot. @FelisCatus

Comment: I'd recommend using the documentation as a reference and using the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) as a primer for common tasks, like file I/O.

Comment: @fatalError I don't know what you tried, but next time you can try selecting your code in the question editor and then clicking on the Code Sample button in the toolbar, which looks like `{}`.

Comment: @fatalError: Please check our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to correct the code format. However wrong format code also better than an image, I don't know how did FelisCatus *type all your code by hand*...Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try!

It's actually simpler than you think:

```
inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r')
for line in inputFile:
    print line
inputFile.close()
```

This is because Python issues a `readline()` for you in every iteration of that `for` loop.

But what if you want to do it yourself, just to learn how it is done?

```
inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r')

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the first line
print lineToRead

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the second line
print lineToRead

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the third line
print lineToRead

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the fourth line
print lineToRead

inputFile.close()
```

Try it!

Of course, this only works if `pets.txt` only has 4 lines. In order to improve this, you could put that code in a loop:

```
inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r')

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the first line
print lineToRead

while "there's still lines to read":
    lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the following lines
    print lineToRead

inputFile.close()
```

There's a little problem -- Python doesn't understand what you mean by "there's still lines to read". But, if you read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), you'll notice that `readline()` returns the empty string when it has reached the end of the document. So:

```
inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r')

lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the first line
print lineToRead

while lineToRead != '':
    lineToRead = inputFile.readline() # read the following lines
    print lineToRead

inputFile.close()
```

I hope you were able to follow me. If you weren't, don't worry. Keep trying!